# Java - execution order between Junit tags and Cucumber hook tags - which ones go first?

Tags: java, junit, tags, cucumber, hook

is there any conjunction between Junit tags and Cucumber hook tags execution order ?
I have a project with Cucumber feature file, step definition file and page object model.
In feature file I want use tag `@pageOne` and `@pageTwo`

then in Cucumber hook class I have:

```
public static List<String> list;

@Before(@pageOne) 
public void beforeOne (Scenario scenario) {
list = scenario.getSourceTagsNames().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
}

 @Before(@pageTwo) 
    public void beforeOne (Scenario scenario) {
    list = scenario.getSourceTagsNames().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Then in other class I have @Before Junit annotation.

```
@Before
public void setUpProperties() {
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream(appConfigPath));

if (list.contains(@pageOne)) {
String url = properties.getProperty("pageOne");
}

if (list.contains(@pageTwo)) {
String url = properties.getProperty("pageTwo");
}
```

So I have to run @Before cucumber tag earlier than Junit @before tag because I have to pass ivalue from cucumber before method to junit before method.

Is this possible to set annotation tags order ? I want to run cuumber tag earlier than junit tag.

Thank you

Comment: It is not possible to mix Cucumber and JUnit 4 hooks.

Comment: Junit in my project is the runner and I have junit before tags and cucumber before tags in the project

Comment: Only `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` work then. But I think you're on the wrong track for whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: what do you mean BeforeClass and AfterClass ? only these 2 work with cucumber tags ?